# Passing submit input parameter in a AJAX post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm refactoring a form into an AJAX post request.

Here's the existing form:

```
    <%= form_for([@group, @invitation], :remote => true, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :class => 'fbinvite_form', :id => friend[:identifier]}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_email, :value => "facebook@meetcody.com" %>

        <div class = "fbinvite btn_list_right" id = "<%= friend[:identifier] %>">
        <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-medium btn-primary", :name => "fb" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

In the controller I have logic that checks for the name of the submit input:

```
if params[:fb]
... 
elsif params[:somethingelse]
...
end
```

That's the background. I am now trying to replace the above form with the following ajax (added dummy data to make it clearer):

```
$.post('/groups/7/invitations', { 
  "recipient_email": "facebook@meetcody.com",
  "commit" : "fb",
  "fb" : "fb"
}, function(response) {
  alert("invite created!");
});
```

This successfully hits the controller, but doesn't evaluate as true on the condition `if params[:fb]`. As you can see I tried some really basic ways of passing that parameter in, but it obviously didn't work.

How can I change my ajax request so that `params[:fb]` evaluates as `true`?

Comment: May not be relevant but you have an extra brace there

Comment: Sorry that was a sloppy copy and paste. Investigating further it looks like the params[:fb] is, in fact, evaluating true. For some reason it isn't assigning the recipient_email. I do this upfront with a Invitation.new(params[:invitation]) call. I'm guessing the ajax request doesn't wrap everything up under [:invitation]

Comment: And that seems to have fixed it (explicitly calling params[:recipient_email] instead of params[:invitation]).